# Problem connect turtlebot and workstation

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
After I have followed the tutorials , the connection between my turtlebot2 and the workstation still doesn't work,
I have set ROS_MASTER_URI , ROS_HOSTNAME in both the workstation and the turtlebot netbook.
when I'm trying to do :
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
(after I've ssh'd to the turtlebot netbook)

I get these errors:

core service [/rosout] found
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [2978]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[diagnostic_aggregator-2]: started with pid [2980]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3]: started with pid [2982]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[mobile_base-4]: started with pid [2984]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
[robot_state_publisher-1] process has died [pid 2978, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/robot_state_publisher-1.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/robot_state_publisher-1*.log
[diagnostic_aggregator-2] process has died [pid 2980, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node __name:=diagnostic_aggregator __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/diagnostic_aggregator-2.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/diagnostic_aggregator-2*.log
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [2986]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [2988]
[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3] process has died [pid 2982, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3*.log
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-7]: started with pid [2990]
[mobile_base-4] process has died [pid 2984, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager mobile_base/odom:=odom mobile_base/enable:=enable mobile_base/disable:=disable mobile_base/joint_states:=joint_states __name:=mobile_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/mobile_base-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/mobile_base-4*.log
[cmd_vel_mux-5] process has died [pid 2986, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager cmd_vel_mux/output:=mobile_base/commands/velocity __name:=cmd_vel_mux __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/cmd_vel_mux-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/cmd_vel_mux-5*.log
[bumper2pointcloud-6] process has died [pid 2988, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud:=mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud bumper2pointcloud/core_sensors:=mobile_base/sensors/core __name:=bumper2pointcloud __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/bumper2pointcloud-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/bumper2pointcloud-6*.log
[WARN] [WallTime: 1438594577.419304] Battery : unable to check laptop battery info [global name 'exceptions' is not defined]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1438594577.422830] Battery : unable to check laptop battery state [global name 'exceptions' is not defined]
[turtlebot_laptop_battery-7] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ed2507e6-39c0-11e5-9712-c4d987c9f05e/turtlebot_laptop_battery-7*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215130/problem-connect-turtlebot-and-workstation/) by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've found a way to make it work,
apprently the problew was in
"  what(): locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid process"
the solution is by :
" export LC_ALL="C" "
in my understanding it means that the code is written in C (language).
if anybody can tell otherwise i will be happy to learn.

---

Originally posted by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) with karma: 33 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nagarjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/47555/nagarjun/) on 2020-11-15**:
I didn't understand your solution, Can you please detail it?